# Instagram Basic Display API - Query User's 'Saved' Videos?

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

If anyone familiar with this API could verify, I'd appreciate it.

Does the Instagram Basic Display API allow one to query a user's saved videos? These saved videos would be video content created by other Instagram users.

If I can extract even just the URLs of these saved videos, that'd be enough for my use case.

Thank you for reading my message!

I'm currently setting up my FB developer account to test this myself, but thought I'd ask in case anyone has tried this and encountered any technical blocks.

Comment: any updates on this?